# Redirect Firebase Hosting root to a Cloud Function is not working

Tags: javascript, express, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm using Firebase Hosting with a `firebase.json` file that is supposed to forward all traffic to a cloud function (prerender) which populates meta and og tags for SEO.

```
{
  "hosting": {
      "public": "dist/prod",
      "rewrites": [
       {
          "source": "**",
          "function": "prerender"
       }
      ]
   }
}
```

My `prerender` function is is handling the request and rendering the HTML file. This works fine:

```
export const prerender = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   console.log('prerender function: "' + req.path + '"');
   ...
}
```

When hitting the end point at `https://xxx.cloudfunctions.net/prerender`, I correctly get the call in the Firebase Dashboard under Functions -> Logs:

```
prerender function: "null"
```

However, when calling `https://mypage.firebaseapp.com`, I get no logs and it seems to render the `index.html` inside of my `dist/prod` folder.

Is there anything I'm missing with the rewrites? I tried rewriting `/` to the same function, but no success. Any hints much appreciated!

Comment: Detailed solution with NestJS on the server is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57493514/11127383

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should be able to route all URLs to a function in exactly the way you're showing.  I'm guessing that you still have an index.html file located in your dist/prod directory.  In my test project, I simply renamed the root index.html to something else, and requests to `/` were routed to my function.

**It turns out that if there is static web content that matches the client request URL, that will be served instead of delegating to the function.**  This is true for any incoming URL.  The only way to truly ensure that *all* requests are routed to your function is to remove *all* content from your `dist/prod` folder before deploying.

I believe the key piece of information is in the documentation for [rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-rewrites):

> A rewrite rule is only applied if a file or folder does not exist at
>   the specified source, and returns the actual content of the file at
>   the destination instead of an HTTP redirect.